# Why SSRS report is loading very slowing in user PC

Tags: reporting-services

Anyone please clarify this problem:

1. Why is SSRS report loading very slowly from user PC in same domain but inside server is faster?

   I have configured SSRS report in server and if I am running report server URL inside the server where my report is deployed is faster(3s) but when user is accessing same URL from their PC in same domain it's very very slow(5 mins).

   If after click on view button , if it's taking time then I may guess that may be data is huge but my case if no data also for initialize reporting viewer taking long time.

   I have checked stored procedure result, it's very fast.
2. In Chrome browser report viewer is not loading properly, it's not loading properly in chrome browser. any chrome setting required?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to investigate this for yourself using a packet-sniffing tool like WireShark.